# Find $\sin81^\circ$ given $\sin18^\circ=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\sin18^\circ=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}$, then $\sin81^\circ$ is equal to
>   \begin{align}
> &a)\quad\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{4}\\
> &b)\quad\frac{\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}+\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}}{4}\\
> &c)\quad\frac{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}{4}
> \end{align}

$$
\cos18^\circ=\sqrt{1-\frac{6-2\sqrt{5}}{16}}=\frac{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}{4}
$$
$$
\sin81^\circ=\cos9^\circ=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos18^\circ}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{4+\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}{8}}=\frac{\sqrt{8+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}}{4}
$$
How do I proceed further and find the solution ?

Or from here, at least can I just identify the solution as $\sin81^\circ=\dfrac{\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}+\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}}{4}$ from the options given ?

Comment: recall that $\cos 2x= \cos^2x -\sin^2x=2\cos^2x-1$$

Comment: @ALG pls check OP, I did that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you suspect (b) is the answer, just square it. You'll get
$$
\frac1{16}\left(3 +\sqrt 5+2\sqrt{(3+\sqrt 5)(5-\sqrt 5)} + 5 - \sqrt 5\right)
$$
which simplifies to
$$
\frac1{16}\left(8 + 2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt 5}\right),
$$
the square of your answer. Your answer must then agree with (b), since both answers are positive (as is $\sin 81^\circ$).

Comment: @ss1729 Your answer is $x:=\frac{\sqrt{8+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}}{4}$. To show this is the same as $b:=\dfrac{\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}+\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}}{4}$, you compute $x^2$ and compare it to $b^2$. You'll find they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin81^\circ = \sin(45 + 36)\\
\sin45\cos 36 + \cos 45\sin 36$

$\cos 36 = 1 - 2\sin^2 18 = \frac {1+\sqrt 5}{4}$

$\sin 36 =$$ \sqrt {\frac {1-\cos 72}{2}}\\ 
\sqrt {\frac {1-\sin 18}{2}}\\
\sqrt {\frac {5-\sqrt 5}{8}}\\
\cos 45\sin 36 = \frac {\sqrt{5-\sqrt5}}{4}$

$\sin 81 = \frac {\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 10}{8} + \frac {\sqrt{5-\sqrt5}}{4}$

But they have pulled a dirty trick on you.

$3+\sqrt{5} = \frac 12 (1+\sqrt{5})^2\\
\frac {\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}}{4} = \frac {1}{\sqrt 2} \frac {1+\sqrt{5}}{4} = \sin 45\cos 36$